# Send DropDownList Value as parameter to ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to use @Html.ActionLink and send the value of my @Html.DropDownList selected item.

here is my code:

```
          <span class="MemberList">
                  @Html.DropDownList("ParticipantList", new SelectList(ViewBag.ParticipantList, "UserName", "UserName", ViewBag.ParticipantList), new { @class = "members" })
          </span>
          <span>
                   @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Impersonate", "Studio", new { username = DropDown.SelectedValue }, new { @class = "gobutton3" })
          </span>
```

So I am wondering how could I send the value to the ActionLink

Comment: it will work...      @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Impersonate", "Studio", new { username = ViewBag.ParticipantList }, new { @class = "gobutton3" })

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only way to add dynamic content to a link is through script

```
<a class="lnkLogin" href="#">Login</a>
```

and then in your script

```
$('.lnkLogin').on('click', function(){
    var url = '@Url.Action("Impersonate", "Studio", new { username = "----" })';
    url = url.replace("----", $('#ParticipantList').val());
    window.location = url;
});
```

this will redirect using the window.location.  being a login you may want to do an ajax call to verify credentials before redirecting.

Comment: I just tried this and I got an error: No overload for method 'Content' takes 3 arguments

Comment: I updated a little bit and it works now here is what I used:

$('#lnkLogin').on('click', function () {
        var url = "../Studio/Impersonate/?username=";
        url = url + $('#ParticipantList').val();
        window.location = url;
    });

Comment: thinking about it, I remembered that wrong.  It is Url.Action, not Url.Content.  I am sorry for the confusion on that.  I am glad that you were able to get it working.